# TouchXML parsing error

Tags: objective-c, xml, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, touchxml

I have a xml document which has only one element in the document. This is the whole document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>key ! is invalid</error>
```

But when i try to parse it, it says this document has no element at all. In other words when i try to access the rootElement it says "null"

Here is the code i am using.

```
   CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

   NSLog(@"Root: %@",[[rssParser rootElement] name]);
```

But its working OK when i have the following document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>angstrom|angstrom unit|A|metric linear unit</synonyms></list>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>vitamin A|antiophthalmic factor|axerophthol|A|fat-soluble vitamin</synonyms></list>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>deoxyadenosine monophosphate|A|nucleotide</synonyms></list>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>adenine|A|purine</synonyms></list>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>ampere|amp|A|current unit</synonyms></list>

<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>A|letter a|letter|letter of the alphabet|alphabetic character</synonyms></list>
<list><category>(noun)</category><synonyms>A|type A|group A|blood group|blood type</synonyms></list>
</response>
```

Please tell me what is wroing with this.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question, showing the whole document i am getting in response.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it's clearly wrong. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

If your up for trying a different parser, I would recommend using TBXML ...its well documented and probably the fastest and best parser around.